# open ant design popover from two link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, popover

I have two component: 1:StudentList  2: Major in react and antd.

`StudentList Component` rendered a list of students.
`Major Component` made a list of majors that you can pick them. After selecting major, the selected major title display on the top of the students list. and the list will be filtered according to the selected major.

This is StudentList component contain Major component:

```
class StudentList extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <>
      <Major/>
      <h5>20 student found in <a>selected major</a></h5>
     
      <List>
      //this is the list of students and is not related to this question
      </List>
      </>);
  }
 }
```

This is Major Component with a filter button to open the popover:

```
class Major extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Popover
        trigger="click"
        content={content} //list of majors
      >
        <Button>
            <FilterOutlined /> Select major to filter
        </Button>
      </Popover>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the `Select major to filter` button, the popover open to select majors. I want to change the code in order to open this popover from  two place:

1- click on `Select major to filter` button in the Major component

2- click on `selected major` in the title in StudentList component.

Notice: I want to open the same popover in the same place (similar to when I click on `Select major to filter` button)

Maybe it could handle with `state` and `handleVisibleChange` function. but I don't know how to handle it from 2 components. I glad to hearing your solutions.

Comment: `Popover` shares API with `Tooltip`. You can use `visible` property to toggle your `Popover` but you'll have to handle all show-hide events by yourself. Also you can just trigger `click` event on Major's `Button`. https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `visible` and `onVisibleChange` property from [Antd's tooltip](https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#Common-API) because they are used by the `PopOver` as well. You can find an easy [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/prdof) from Andt [how to control a PopOver by `visible`](https://ant.design/components/popover/#components-popover-demo-control) in the docs.

To get the button click you can use `onClick` from [antd's Button Api](https://ant.design/components/button/#API).

The desired example using React Components:

```
class Major extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
    if (this.props.value !== prevProps.value) {
      this.setState({ visible: this.props.value });
    }
  }

  state = {
    visible: false
  };

  hide = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  };

  handleVisibleChange = visible => {
    this.setState({ visible });
    // this.props.onChange(visible); // add me to open popover on every click on studenlist
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Popover
        trigger="click"
        content={<a onClick={this.hide}>Close</a>}
        visible={this.state.visible}
        onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
      >
        <Button>Select major to filter</Button>
      </Popover>
    );
  }
}

class StudentList extends Component {
  state = {
    visible: false
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* <Major value={this.state.visible} onChange={setVisible} /> */}
        <Major value={this.state.visible} />
        <h5>
          20 student found in <a>selected major</a>
        </h5>

        <Button onClick={this.onClick}>Select major from Studenlist</Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Component example as a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-taussig-nzzys?file=/index.js:168-1454).

---

Here is a simple example for your request using [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and simple buttons to open the `PopOver`:

```
function Major({ value, onChange }) {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(value);
  useEffect(() => {
    value && setVisible(value);
  }, [value]);

  const hide = () => setVisible(false);

  const handleVisibleChange = visible => {
    setVisible(visible);
    onChange(visible);
  };

  return (
    <Popover
      trigger="click"
      content={<a onClick={hide}>Close</a>}
      visible={visible}
      onVisibleChange={handleVisibleChange}
    >
      <Button>Select major to filter</Button>
    </Popover>
  );
}

function StudentList() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const onClick = () => {
    setVisible(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Major value={visible} onChange={setVisible} />
      <h5>
        20 student found in <a>selected major</a>
      </h5>

      <Button onClick={onClick}>Select major from Studenlist</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

The depended working [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cray-7l0nz?file=/index.js:189-1074).

---

Edit1: Added React Component example.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works but unfortunately  I am using class component and couldn't use hooks or function components in my project. Do you have any idea in class components? to call `setState` or `handleVisibleChange` function from another component.

Comment: I think it is easy to adapt the given example to use with classes instead of functions, just try it ;-)

Comment: Added example + code using React Components. If you are fine with the answer please accept AND [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).